# Mime Type of Partially Uploaded File

Tags: scala, file-upload, playframework, amazon-s3, mime-types

I am using Play Framework version 2.2 and I am trying to get the mime type of a partially uploaded file so I can do a direct upload to an Amazon S3 instance. What is the best practice for doing this?

I am currently using [FlowJS](https://github.com/flowjs/flow.js) but it doesn't look like they have anything in particular for dealing with mime types. Additionally, I plan on making mobile apps that will use the same API so it would be best if it was on the server side and not the client side.

The only solution I can think of is parsing the extension and mapping that to a mime type, but that sounds like a hacky way to do it.

Comment: Why have the upload pass-through the play server at all and not do a direct upload to S3 using a CORS configuration?

Comment: @LimbSoup I am creating a service that sort of manages the uploads. In order to keep track of all of that I need to do post-processing once the file is uploaded. Wouldn't it make more sense to use my server as a passthrough as opposed to making separate calls to upload the file from the client and then inform my server about it afterwards?

Comment: It seems like a waste of resources to have two IO streams that can be avoided by having users upload directly to S3 with a signed form. To do this I have the client upload the file, then confirm to the server when the upload is finished. The server can then find the file on S3 and change it's properties from there if necessary. Downloads work the same way using signed URLs.